# Analyze NetCDF files using AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue, netcdf4

How do I analyze multiple NetCDF files stored in AWS S3 using AWS services such as Glue or Lambda? Can the NetCDF files be converted to csv? A code sample will be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/cedadev/S3-netcdf-python should help